# css --> <table> --> remove vertical space when table data contains several elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `table data` field that contains a blue square on the top and an icon on the bottom.

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnz6gbkr/3/).

The `height` of the `td` field is `26px` because there is a small vertical space between the `blue_line` div element and the `user_icon` image:
[image]

I want that this vertical space is removed and the new height is `20px`

I was able to do that by adding `position: absolute;`:
[image]

But in my application I use `jquery.ui.resizable` which gives me problems if I add `position: absolute;` to the `.blue_line` div element.

My Question is if there are other ways to remove the vertical space ?

Comment: In this case why you didn't play with margins? other thing you can also rewrite your html without space: `<div class="blue_line"></div><img .../>`

Comment: Give the img tag `vertical-align:top;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display of the `td` Element to `grid`

```
<td style="display: grid;">
    <div class="blue_line"></div>
    <img class="user_icon" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1008/quiet/128/opera.png"/>
</td>
```

Unfortunately this property does not exist in `Internet Explorer`. If you want to support `IE` you'll have to add some more styling and change the display of the `td` Element to `block` and the children's to `flex`

```
<td style="display: block;">
    <div class="blue_line" style="display: flex;"></div>
    <img class="user_icon" style="display: flex;" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1008/quiet/128/opera.png"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi, the IE version works in my JSFiddle but in my application this leads also to a line break in every `td` element becaue I have more than one td element: https://jsfiddle.net/dnz6gbkr/6/

Comment: @ViktorCarlson You could just add it to that `td` Element using `inline style`. Don't do` td{display:grid;}` in `CSS` just add `style="display: grid;"` to that Element. Or even better make a class for it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use background-image property and set the background-position